Evaluating $\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=n \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq n}} 1$

I need to find the sum $$\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=n \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq n}} 1$$

For $n=1$ we have the admissible values of $(i,j,k)$ as: $(1,0,0),(0,1,0), (0,0,1)$ $$\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=1 \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq 1}} 1=1+1+1=3$$
For $n=2$ we have the admissible values of $(i,j,k)$ as: $(2,0,0),(0,2,0), (0,0,2),(1,1,0),(0,1,1),(1,0,1)$
$$\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=2 \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq 2}} 1=1+1+1+1+1+1=6$$

You are looking for the number of weak compositions of $n$ into three parts.  It is not much evidence, but these are triangular numbers

This is a classic stars-and-bars problem.  You want the number of solutions in non-nega integers of $i+j+k=n$.  That number is easily seen (via stars and bars) to be $\binom {n+2}{2}$.

@RobertShore ($+1$)Thank you. Can you please give a proof or reference of this result.

\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\sum_{i = 0}^{n} \sum_{j = 0}^{n} \sum_{k = 0}^{n}
\left[z^{n}\right]z^{i\ +\ j\ +\ k}} =
\left[z^{n}\right]\left(\sum_{i = 0}^{n}z^{i}\right)^{3}
\\[5mm] = & \
\left[z^{n}\right]\left(1 - z^{n + 1}\right)^{3}\left(1 - z\right)^{-3}
\\[5mm] = & \ \left[z^{n}\right]\left(1 - z\right)^{-3} =
{-3 \choose n}\left(-1\right)^{n}
\\[5mm] = & \ {3 + n - 1 \choose n} =
\color{#44f}{\left(n + 2\right)\left(n + 1\right) \over 2}
\end{align}

Here is a direct approach:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=n \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq n}} 1 &= \sum_{0\le i\le n}\left(\sum_{\substack{j+k=n-i \\ 0\leq j,k\leq n}}1\right)\\
&= \sum_{0\le i\le n}\left(\sum_{0\le j\le n-i}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{\substack{k=n-i-j \\ 0\leq k\leq n}}1\right)}_{=1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{0\le i\le n}\underbrace{\left(\sum_{0\le j\le n-i}1\right)}_{=n-i+1}\\
&=\sum_{0\le i\le n}(n+1-i)\\
&=(n+1)^2-\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\\
\sum_{\substack{i+j+k=n \\ 0\leq i,j,k\leq n}} 1 &=\frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2} = \pmatrix{n+2\\2}
\end{align}$$

There are $\binom{n+2}{2}$ ways to arrange $n$ stars and $2$ bars in a line.  Interpret the number of stars to the left of both bars as $i$.  Interpret the number of stars between the two bars as $j$. Interpret the number of stars to the right of both stars as $k$.
This interpretation gives you a $1$-$1$ correspondence between (a) arrangements of $n+2$ stars and $2$ bars and (b) ordered triples such that $i+j+k=n$.  Thus, there are $\binom{n+2}{2}$ such triples.
